# Laravel: Authentication

Tags: php, authentication, laravel-5

I'm developing a Laravel project and I want to handle authentication by using the standard authentication model of laravel 5.2
I did a artisan command:

```
php artisan make:auth
```

But it created a view and to connect I have to write email, but for my need I have to use connection by name. 
[image]

Where can I change this?

I cannot find the controller login!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look inside `controllers` -> `Auth` -> `AuthController.php`

This will take you to the controller of where the authentication happens.

Inside of the `AuthController` class add this protected variable:

```
protected $username = 'name';
```

Change `name` to whatever you want to authenticate your user with, this should be the name of the column in your DB.